# What does the semicolon do when it is run in a bash command?

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu

For example, when running

```
echo a; echo b
```

in the terminal, its output is:

```
a
b
```

It seems to me that the semicolon waits for the first command (`echo a`) to finish, then it starts the second command (`echo b`).

**Q:** Is the semicolon just used for iterating over commands in bash?

**Q:** What does the semicolon do when it is run in a bash command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `;` separates the two commands.

```
echo a; echo b
```

It lets the bash know that `echo a` and  `echo b` are two separate commands and need to be run separately one after the other

Try without semicolons

```
$ echo a echo b
a echo b
```

Here the statement is taken as a single command `echo` and `a echo b` is passed as parameter to the `echo`

Answer (score 5):

it's a way to simulate a newline.

```
echo a; echo b
```

is equivalent to

> echo a
>
> echo b

Answer (score 2):

It's a statement separator. You could also try

```
sleep 1; echo a
```

which will wait one second and then display a. As would

```
sleep 1 && echo a
```

Comment: As an addition, in the second case (with `&&`), the second statement will execute only if the first is successful.